# Refactor constant to lazy constant using VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I have inherited this code

```
// utils/isMobileView.js
const isMobileView = window.innerWidth < 500;
export default isMobileView;

// somewhere else
import isMobileView from 'utils/isMobileView';
// ...
if (isMobileView) renderMobile()
else renderDesktop()
```

The problem is obvious. The truthiness is evaluated only **once** on page load.

I would like to refactor it to an evaluating function instead:

```
// utils/isMobileView.js
const isMobileView = () => window.innerWidth < 500;
export default isMobileView;

// somewhere else
import isMobileView from 'utils/isMobileView';
// ...
if (isMobileView()) renderMobile()
else renderDesktop()
```

Is there a way to do that *automagically* leveraging VSCode amazing capabilities?

*Note that this question isn't about using regex, but native **refactoring** functions of VSCode or extensions.*

Comment: Ctrl + F, `isMobileView` replace with `isMobileView()` ...

Comment: @MoshFeu VScode and visual studio aren't necessarily documented in the same place

Comment: Straightforward replacing isn't possible due to import statements that share the same text. Also the `isMobileView` is not used only within `if (...)` statements, but also with ternary and binary operators such as: `isMobileView && otherCondition ? true : false`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there **isn't** such a functionality *(yet)*, so if regex isn't an option for any reason, it is possible to use the excellent find/replace panel in VSCode and manually Apply (Replace) or Dismiss results one by one.

[image]

Comment: @JonasWilms Nice one. Improved a little: `(?<!import.+)isMobileView`. https://regex101.com/r/0ZSvSF/2

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+shift+p `Search: Find in Files` and then look for `isMobileView` and replace with `isMobileView()`

Comment: Unfortunatelly this will also replace imports as the file is named `isMobileView.js`. I know I can regex, but that's out of the scope of the question.

Comment: @Qwerty it seems like its used only in if statements, therefor you could try look for `(isMobileView)` other than that vscode, doesnt provide functionality for this, its refactor fuctions isnt that smart to not replace imports aswel

Comment: I updated my question with `import isMobileView from 'utils/isMobileView'` - the reason why simple replace won't work. Also it is used as this `isMobileView && (something)`.

Comment: @Qwerty in that case I would do two replaces `(isMobileView` and `isMobileView &&`, yes in the first one I would use only one parenthese, if this doesnt isnt enough, Iam affraid there isnt better solution that vscode would offer